# Can't set 'background-image' with jQuery using a variable

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to set the background image of a DIV with jQuery. The image's path is stored in a variable. I have verified that the image's path is valid using the console + copy/paste.

Here's the code:

```
var bg = $('.temp-canvas', this).attr('data-background');
$(this).css('background-image', 'url('+bg+')');
```

$(this) is used because this is run in a .each() loop.

This code adds nothing to the DIV. Replacing, in the code, '+bg+' by the string stored the bg variable works like a charm. I would at least expect the code would add style="background-image:url('invalid_path')" but nothing is added. I'm simply baffled!

Comment: So what does `'url('+bg+')'` end up evaluating to?

Comment: Can you console.log(bg) ?

Comment: To something invalid. Corrected it and everything is fine now. It's weird though that nothing was added to the DIV, even though the path was invalid. Thanks!

Comment: @BrunoCloutier: Please supply an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: working demo here **http://jsfiddle.net/vnf6D/**

create a class which includes the second photo you want to have.

```
.canvas
{
   background-image: url(your-image.jpg);
}
```

then add this class with the event you wish on jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".temp-canvas").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("canvas2");
  });
});
```